# mongo-connector error on ubuntu 14.14

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, elasticsearch, pymongo

The mongoconnector has worked previously, but now it is not.  Here is part of the very long trace of the error:

```
...
   return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic2_doc_manager.py", line 203, in bulk_upsert
    for ok, resp in responses:
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 160, in streaming_bulk
    for result in _process_bulk_chunk(client, bulk_actions, raise_on_exception, raise_on_error, **kwargs):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 132, in _process_bulk_chunk
    raise BulkIndexError('%i document(s) failed to index.' % len(errors), errors)
BulkIndexError: (u'86 document(s) failed to index.', [{u'index': {u'status': 400, u'_type': u'wikis', u'_id': u'574f3f9253a18f8397ecc13a', u'error': {u'caused_by': {u'reason': u'Cannot parse "+1960-00-00T00:00:00Z": Value 0 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]', u'type': u'illegal_field_value_exception'}, u'reason': u'failed to parse [claims.P1082.qualifiers.P585.datavalue.value.time]', u'type': u'mapper_parsing_exception'}, u'_index': u'test1'}}, 
...
2016-06-01 21:32:55,806 [ERROR] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:557 - OplogThread: Failed during dump collection cannot recover! Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'local'), u'oplog.rs')
2016-06-01 21:32:56,618 [ERROR] mongo_connector.connector:302 - MongoConnector: OplogThread <OplogThread(Thread-6, started 139915396376320)> unexpectedly stopped! Shutting down
```

#### Starting MongoDB just outside:

$ mongod --dbpath data --replSet "rs0" #create replica set on port 27017

$ mongo #initiate replica set

Inside the mongo repl, I type:

> rs.initiate({"_id" : "rs0","version" : 1,"members" : [{"_id" : 0,"host" : "localhost:27017"}]})

Elasticsearch is already started on port 9200.

#### Altogether now

$ mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager

...then I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying error looks like

```
{u'reason': u'Cannot parse "+1960-00-00T00:00:00Z": Value 0 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]', u'type': u'illegal_field_value_exception'}
```

That simply means that one of your documents in MongoDB has an invalid date `+1960-00-00T00:00:00Z` with an invalid month (`00`) and day (`00`).

You need to find that record and fix it, after that the replication will work, provided you don't have another record with the same problem.

Comment: I could fix it but I expect there to be a lot like this.  Do you know how to add an argument to the mongo-connector to tell it to ignore errors when copying from MongoDB to Elasticsearch?

Comment: Indeed, 86 document(s) failed to index. It's not mongo-connector that errors out, but simply reports what Elasticsearch is complaining about. As the saying goes, if you let garbage in, you'll get garbage out. You should validate the data before it enters MongoDB

Comment: Any news about this?

Comment: I was pulled into another project but I will update when I come back to this. Just to note, 86 articles failing out of millions is an acceptable error rate for me (for Wikipedia). Also, I found a blog post that loads Wikipedia directly into Elasticsearch.   While not as straightforward, it also means that a copy of gigabytes worth of data will be avoided.